# XML Node naming

Tags: c#, xml, dom, nodes

So here is my XML, and i understand that the OrderDate, BuyerID and Items are called childnodes, however what do you call the attributes within the Items such as ItemName, Category ect.. Are they still called childnodes? If so what should they be called?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<OrderData >

    <Order OrderID="OR00001">
      <OrderDate>26 May 2017</OrderDate>
      <BuyerID>WCS1810001</BuyerID>
      <Instructions>Place item carefully</Instructions>

      <Items ItemID="IT00001">
        <ItemName>ASUS Monitor</ItemName>
        <Description>Best monitor in the world</Description>
        <Category>Monitor</Category>
        <Quantities>100</Quantities>
        <Manufacturer>ASUS</Manufacturer>
        <UnitPrice>$100.00</UnitPrice>
      </Items>
  </Order>
</OrderData>
```

Comment: It depends on your reference point.  Items is a child of Order.  ItemName is a child of Items, and is a descendant of Order.

Comment: @dbasnett Hmm so lets say if i were to try to process the items attributes and normally to process the child node would be like this, order.BuyerID=node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText; . What would it look like for the Items attributes ?

Comment: Items has one attribute, ItemID.  Is that what you are referring to?  I am a VB'er so I don't know how you would get that attribute.  IMO VB is easier when working with XML.

Answer (score 0):

The only attributes you have, in xml terms, are your OrderID and ItemID attributes. When working with xml, it's helpful to just use the xml terminology. Accordingly, everything else in your xml is an **element **.

Any element that is under another element is a child element of that element.

Items is a child element of Order, and ItemName is a child element of Items.

Comment: They have an OrderID as an attribute of Order FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Why MS did not add this to C# is beyond me.  VB seems better suited to work with XML IMHO.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    ' to load from a file
    ' Dim yourpath As String = "your path here"
    'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)

    ' for testing
    xe = <OrderData>
             <Order OrderID="OR00001">
                 <OrderDate>26 May 2017</OrderDate>
                 <BuyerID>WCS1810001</BuyerID>
                 <Instructions>Place item carefully</Instructions>
                 <Items ItemID="IT00001">
                     <ItemName>ASUS Monitor</ItemName>
                     <Description>Best monitor in the world</Description>
                     <Category>Monitor</Category>
                     <Quantities>100</Quantities>
                     <Manufacturer>ASUS</Manufacturer>
                     <UnitPrice>$100.00</UnitPrice>
                 </Items>
             </Order>
         </OrderData>

    Dim item As XElement
    'this does not find an item
    item = (From el In xe...<Items>
            Where el.@ItemID = "IT"
            Select el).FirstOrDefault

    If item Is Nothing Then Stop

    'this finds the item
    item = (From el In xe...<Items>
            Where el.@ItemID = "IT00001"
            Select el).FirstOrDefault

    'add a new item to the order.  an item prototype
    Dim itmProto As XElement = <Items ItemID="">
                                   <ItemName></ItemName>
                                   <Description></Description>
                                   <Category></Category>
                                   <Quantities></Quantities>
                                   <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>
                                   <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
                               </Items>

    Dim newItem As New XElement(itmProto) 'note that itmProto is not used directly, only as part of New
    newItem.@ItemID = "ITM0042"
    newItem.<ItemName>.Value = "FOO"
    newItem.<Description>.Value = "this is a test"
    'etc
    xe.<Order>.Last.Add(newItem) 'add to order

    ' to save file
    ' xe.Save(yourpath)
```